# Docker CE and syslog

Tags: docker, syslog

Docker logging drivers are specified online, and these limitations.

> Limitations of logging drivers
>
> Users of Docker Enterprise can make use of “dual logging”, which enables you to use the docker logs command for any logging driver. Refer to reading logs when using remote logging drivers for information about using docker logs to read container logs locally for many third party logging solutions, including:
>
> syslog
>
> gelf
>
> fluentd
>
> awslogs
>
> splunk
>
> etwlogs
>
> gcplogs
>
> Logentries
>
> When using Docker Community Engine, the docker logs command is only available on the following drivers:
>
> local
>
> json-file
>
> journald
>
> Reading log information requires decompressing rotated log files, which causes a temporary increase in disk usage (until the log entries from the rotated files are read) and an increased CPU usage while decompressing.
>
> The capacity of the host storage where the Docker data directory resides determines the maximum size of the log file information.

I am using Docker CE, but I have a question about this documentation. Does this mean, using CE, I cant do syslog at all? or just that I cant do syslog and have docker logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from using syslog within the container, but you can't read those logs using the 'docker logs' command. There is also nothing stopping you from writing your logs to stdout and piping your logs to as many log shippers as you want.

Here's an article that explains how to do syslog in a docker container: https://medium.com/better-programming/docker-centralized-logging-with-syslog-97b9c147bd30

I think that fluentd and fluent-bit are better choices than syslog these days given the structure they provide to the msg field, though syslog-ng looks interesting. Fluent-bit is incredibly good though, so you might want to take a look at it.